# OneDrive for Business not working on iPad

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, onedrive-for-business

I have created a test environment, specifically for document shareing, using SharePoint 2013. Everything works fine (OneDrive for Business is installed locally on my PC) however the iPad app does not work properply.

[image: error message]

Excuse me for the Dutch language. I was not able to find the appropriate error message on internet (due to it's being translated). The error is (roughly translated):

```
Site not found

You are signed in but your library is not found. 
Try logging in with your browser first and then return to this application.
```

Logging in through the browser works fine and I get to see the libraries (or apps as they call them in SharePoint 2013).

Does anyone has a clue on what's going on? Does this error sound familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 1):

After spending hours of searching, I have fixed this by clicking the **OneDrive** link in the top right corner of SharePoint 2013, which showed "OneDrive". Clicking this will create the files (and it seems OneDrive for Business doesn't work with a team site - hence the confusion.